# How can i manipulate json values

Tags: javascript, python, json, python-3.x

I have a rest api that returns json of a query on database & the json looks like

```
{"keys": "[{'aht': Decimal('238'), 'month': 'April '}, {'aht': Decimal('201'), 'month': 'August '}, {'aht': Decimal('236'), 'month': 'December '}, {'aht': Decimal('230'), 'month': 'February '}, {'aht': Decimal('228'), 'month': 'January '}, {'aht': Decimal('202'), 'month': 'July '}, {'aht': Decimal('201'), 'month': 'June '}, {'aht': Decimal('239'), 'month': 'March '}, {'aht': Decimal('214'), 'month': 'May '}, {'aht': Decimal('235'), 'month': 'November '}, {'aht': Decimal('221'), 'month': 'October '}, {'aht': Decimal('147'), 'month': 'September'}]", "success": true}
```

So from below

```
{'aht': Decimal('238'), 'month': 'April '}
```

Remove Decimal()

Expected:

```
{'aht': '238', 'month': 'April '}
```

I can handle it in python 3.6 or in js.

Comment: You'll need to handle it BEFORE sending it, otherwise you're not sending JSON - therefore your only option is whatever server side language you use - you'll also need to change all `'` to `"` for valid JSON .. at the moment, though, you actually have JSON which would result in an object `{keys: "[{... this is just string value for keys...}]"}` - so technically your server is creating something that isn't even close to JSON

Answer (score 2):

You can try to pre-process JSON string before you use it in your application as below.

Or, if you want your REST API to send this output to use with something else and only problem is with JS/Python(when you want to process it as JSON), implement a parameter for your rest endpoint to specify whether cleanup(JSON formatting) necessary or not. Based on that parameter, do the necessary processing in server side to remove Decimal etc.

```js
let str = `{"keys": "[{'aht': Decimal('2'), 'month': 'April '}, {'aht': Decimal('20'), 'month': 'August '}, {'aht': Decimal('236'), 'month': 'December '}, {'aht': Decimal('230'), 'month': 'February '}, {'aht': Decimal('228'), 'month': 'January '}, {'aht': Decimal('202'), 'month': 'July '}, {'aht': Decimal('201'), 'month': 'June '}, {'aht': Decimal('239'), 'month': 'March '}, {'aht': Decimal('214'), 'month': 'May '}, {'aht': Decimal('235'), 'month': 'November '}, {'aht': Decimal('221'), 'month': 'October '}, {'aht': Decimal('147'), 'month': 'September'}]", "success": true}`;

let cleanJSON = str.replace(/Decimal\('([0-9]*)'\)/g, function(x) {
  return x.substring(9, x.length - 2);
});

console.log(JSON.parse(cleanJSON));
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Jaromanda said, your API data is not in the format you want. Please check it again. If you getting data like I have mentioned here, you can use my method.

```js
var jsonData = {"keys": [{'aht': "Decimal('238')", 'month': 'April '}, {'aht': "Decimal('201')", 'month': 'August '}, {'aht': "Decimal('236')", 'month': 'December '}, {'aht': "Decimal('230')", 'month': 'February '}, {'aht': "Decimal('228')", 'month': 'January '}, {'aht': "Decimal('202')", 'month': 'July '}, {'aht': "Decimal('201')", 'month': 'June '}, {'aht': "Decimal('239')", 'month': 'March '}, {'aht': "Decimal('214')", 'month': 'May '}, {'aht': "Decimal('235')", 'month': 'November '}, {'aht': "Decimal('221')", 'month': 'October '}, {'aht': "Decimal('147')", 'month': 'September'}], "success": true}

if( jsonData.keys ) {

  jsonData.keys.map( ( data ) => {
  
    if( data.aht && data.aht.match( /Decimal\(/ ) ) {
    
      data.aht = data.aht.replace( "Decimal('", "" );
      data.aht = data.aht.replace( "')", "" );
    
    }
  
  } )
  

}

console.log(jsonData.keys)
```

Comment: Data is coming as asked in the question, may be because its a result of nested query with mathematical operations. I see you made difference in the quotes which you used as input here.

Answer (score 1):

It will be easier to convert this to the string representation of a dict and then make an actual dict of it using `ast.literal_eval` (more secure than using plain Python `eval`). You'll have to do the following steps:

1. replace all Decimal('111') strings with just '111'.
2. replace 'true' and 'false' with 'True' and 'False'
3. evaluate the overall dict using `ast.literal_eval`
4. evaluate the "keys" dict value using a second call to `ast.literal_eval`

Looks like this:

```
import re
import ast

def make_dict(s):
    # extract integer part of Decimal values
    ss = re.sub(r"Decimal\('(\d+)'\)", r"\1", s)

    # convert boolean literals
    ss = ss.replace("true", "True")
    ss = ss.replace("false", "False")

    # convert dict
    dictval = ast.literal_eval(ss)

    # convert 'keys' entry
    dictval['keys'] = ast.literal_eval(dictval['keys'])

    return dictval
```

Here it is in action:

```
text = """{"keys": "[{'aht': Decimal('238'), 'month': 'April '}, {'aht': Decimal('201'), 'month': 'August '}, {'aht': Decimal('236'), 'month': 'December '}, {'aht': Decimal('230'), 'month': 'February '}, {'aht': Decimal('228'), 'month': 'January '}, {'aht': Decimal('202'), 'month': 'July '}, {'aht': Decimal('201'), 'month': 'June '}, {'aht': Decimal('239'), 'month': 'March '}, {'aht': Decimal('214'), 'month': 'May '}, {'aht': Decimal('235'), 'month': 'November '}, {'aht': Decimal('221'), 'month': 'October '}, {'aht': Decimal('147'), 'month': 'September'}]", "success": true}"""

import pprint
pprint.pprint(make_dict(text))
```

Gives:

```
{'keys': [{'aht': 238, 'month': 'April '},
          {'aht': 201, 'month': 'August '},
          {'aht': 236, 'month': 'December '},
          {'aht': 230, 'month': 'February '},
          {'aht': 228, 'month': 'January '},
          {'aht': 202, 'month': 'July '},
          {'aht': 201, 'month': 'June '},
          {'aht': 239, 'month': 'March '},
          {'aht': 214, 'month': 'May '},
          {'aht': 235, 'month': 'November '},
          {'aht': 221, 'month': 'October '},
          {'aht': 147, 'month': 'September'}],
 'success': True}
```

Please tell people to stop storing dicts in your database by converting them to strings using `str`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use string `replace()` with RegEx like the following way:

```js
var keysObj = {"keys": "[{'aht': Decimal('238'), 'month': 'April '}, {'aht': Decimal('201'), 'month': 'August '}, {'aht': Decimal('236'), 'month': 'December '}, {'aht': Decimal('230'), 'month': 'February '}, {'aht': Decimal('228'), 'month': 'January '}, {'aht': Decimal('202'), 'month': 'July '}, {'aht': Decimal('201'), 'month': 'June '}, {'aht': Decimal('239'), 'month': 'March '}, {'aht': Decimal('214'), 'month': 'May '}, {'aht': Decimal('235'), 'month': 'November '}, {'aht': Decimal('221'), 'month': 'October '}, {'aht': Decimal('147'), 'month': 'September'}]", "success": true};

keysObj.keys = keysObj.keys.replace(/Decimal[\(^0-9]|\)/g, '');
console.log(keysObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

As everyone says, best thing you can do is to tell the middle-ware guy to do the job because it's an unnecessary load for the front-end. Otherwise you can replace the Decimal() and ' using regex (JavaScript).

```js
var jsonObj = {"keys": "[{'aht': Decimal('238'), 'month': 'April '}, {'aht': Decimal('201'), 'month': 'August '}, {'aht': Decimal('236'), 'month': 'December '}, {'aht': Decimal('230'), 'month': 'February '}, {'aht': Decimal('228'), 'month': 'January '}, {'aht': Decimal('202'), 'month': 'July '}, {'aht': Decimal('201'), 'month': 'June '}, {'aht': Decimal('239'), 'month': 'March '}, {'aht': Decimal('214'), 'month': 'May '}, {'aht': Decimal('235'), 'month': 'November '}, {'aht': Decimal('221'), 'month': 'October '}, {'aht': Decimal('147'), 'month': 'September'}]", "success": true}

// cleans the JSON object to generate a valid JSON.
jsonObj.keys = jsonObj.keys.replace(/Decimal[\(^0-9]|\)/g, '').replace(/'/gm, '"');
jsonObj.keys = JSON.parse(jsonObj.keys);

console.log(jsonObj);
```